# openstack: The visibility of availability zone

Tags: openstack, availability-zone

Is it possible that one availability_zone/host_aggregate could be only used by only one specified project in openstack?

Answer (score 0):

What you need can be achieved setting metadata to host aggregates with the tenant id in a similar fashion as multi-tenant isolation should do.

```
nova aggregate-set-metadata <aggregate_ID> filter_tenant_id=<tenant_ID>
```

Regards